# Ensure infinitely looping threads are stopped when main application crashes

Tags: java, multithreading

I have created a Runnable class responsible for monitoring a directory for file changes.

```
... imports ...

public class ExamplePathWatch implments Runnable {
    ...
    private boolean isRunning = true;
    ...

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(isRunning) {
            [1]... wait for a file change ...
            [2]... notify listeners of file change (if any) ...
        }
    }

    public synchronized void stopPathWatch() {
        isRunning = false;
        ... interrupt [1] and allow the thred to exit immediately...
    }
```

The thread pauses at **[1]** until a file change occurs, or `stopPathWatch()` method is called which sets `isRunning = false` and interrupts current waiting at **[1]**.

Right before the main application exits, the `stopPathWatch()` is called which allows the thread to exit and the entire application to completely terminate.

My problem is that when there is an application crash, the main application terminates, without the `stopPathWatch()` being called. Therefore the application keeps running indefinitely in the background until it is killed through the OS.

As there is quite active development on the application and not all exceptions are handled, is there a recommended way to ensure the child thread is stopped no matter how the main application terminates?

Thanks

Comment: Your application is not crashed if there are any threads still running for it (threads != processes). What is your definition of crash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could run the `ExamplePathWatch` as a daemon thread.  Only threads that are not marked as daemon will prevent the application from exiting.

Comment: Yes, to which I would add: unless there is an overriding reason to explicitly stop/terminate app-lifetime threads, always set them as daemons and don't try.

Answer (score 1):

You can add it as a shutdown hook:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        stopPathWatch();
    }
});
```

This code would have to go somewhere in your program.

Comment: A shutdown hook wouldn't help in this case as the still-running background threads are what is preventing the shutdown from starting in the first place.